# columns validation based on two other columns

Tags: list, validation

I am working on SharePoint and need some help. So I create a tracking log where user will validate information.

For example, if the status is closed, they are required to enter the date and the description of the case. So far date is working fine but description is not working. I tried doing following with no luck.

```
=IF(Status="Closed",IF(description="",IF([Date Closed]>=TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE))
```

Can someone help? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    =IF([Status]="Closed",IF(ISBLANK([Description]),FALSE,IF([Date Close]>TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE)),TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, it did not work for Description. Once they select closed and enter dates, user are not even required to put any Description. Any ideas on how to solve it? Thank you for your help.